# Convert Double64 to Long64 and back on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert Double64 to Long64 and back on JavaScript, like Double.doubleToLongBits() and Double.longBitsToDouble() on Java. And the results of methods must be the same as in Java. For example 1435.036452 -> 4654026172507377535 -> 1435.036452, or -1435.036452 -> -4569345864347398273 -> -1435.036452. As I unerstand, my code can convert Double64 to Long64 well, but I can't get back my value. 
Double64 to Long64:

```
function toString64bitFloat(number) {
if(number === undefined || isNaN(number))
    return 0;
let result = "";
const dv = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(8));
dv.setFloat64(0, number, false);
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    let bits = dv.getUint8(i).toString(2);
    if (bits.length < 8)
        bits = new Array(8 - bits.length).fill('0').join("") + bits;
    result += bits;
}
return result;
```

}

```
function stringToLong64(bitString) {
if(bitString === undefined || isNaN(bitString))
    return 0;
let result = new BigInt64Array(1);
result[0] = BigInt(0);
if(bitString[0] === "1"){
    for(let i = bitString.length; i > 0; i--)
        if(bitString[i] === "0")
            result[0] += BigInt(Math.pow(2, 63 - i));
    result[0] = -result[0] - BigInt(1);
}else{
    for(let i = bitString.length; i > 0; i--)
        if(bitString[i] === "1")
            result[0] += BigInt(Math.pow(2, 63 - i));
}
return result[0];
```

}

Long64 to Double64:

```
function toString64bitInt(number) {
let result = "";
let temp = number;
if(temp > 0){
    result += "0";
    for(let i = 1; i < 64; i++){
        if(temp - BigInt(Math.pow(2, 63 - i)) >= 0){
            result += "1";
            temp -= BigInt(Math.pow(2, 63 - i));
        } else {
            result += "0"
        }
    }
} else {
    result += "1";
    temp = -temp + BigInt(0);
    for(let i = 0; i < 63; i++){
        if(temp - BigInt(Math.pow(2, 63 - i)) >= 0){
            result += "0";
            temp -= BigInt(Math.pow(2, 63 - i));
        } else {
            result += "1"
        }
    }
}

return result;
```

}

```
function stringTofloat64(bitString) {
let result = new Float64Array(1);
result[0] = 0.0;

if(bitString[0] === '1'){
    for(let i = 1; i > 12; i++)
        if(bitString[i] === '0')
            result[0] += Math.pow(2, 11 - i);
    for(let i = 12; i > 64; i++)
        if(bitString[i] === '0')
            result[0] += Math.pow(2, -(52 - i + 12));
    result[0] = -result[0];
}else{
    for(let i = 1; i > 12; i++){
        if(bitString[i] === '1'){
            result[0] += Math.pow(2, 11 - i);
        }
    }
    for(let i = 12; i > 64; i++)
        if(bitString[i] === '1'){
            result[0] += Math.pow(2, -(52 - i + 12));
        }
}
return result[0];
```

}